# Why regex doesn't work some times in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js

Hello I'm using regex to validate inputs, The idea is that the user cannot type some characters based on regex. I tested with 2 regex, but te first doesn't work.
Even I test on that page: https://regexr.com/
and both works fine, but in the code they don't.
Would you please helpme? Thanks.

I need a regex that letme type range betwen 0 and 180

the desired behaviour:

[image]

[image]

```js
function regex1(str) {
  
  var splitStr = str.split("");
  
  var filterArray = splitStr.filter(function(val) {
    
    // Test the string against the regular expression
    // and test for no match (whole thing is preceeded by !)
    return !/^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-7][0-9]|180)$/g.test(val);
  });
  
  return filterArray;
}

function regex2(str) {
  
  var splitStr = str.split("");
  
  var filterArray = splitStr.filter(function(val) {
    
    // Test the string against the regular expression
    // and test for no match (whole thing is preceeded by !)
    return !/[^1-3]+/g.test(val);
  });
  
  return filterArray;
}

console.log(regex1("180"));
console.log(regex2("3"));
```

Comment: What if you try `return !(/[^1-3]+/g.test(val));`?

Comment: I don´t understand your comment. Thas the same that I have in my code.
The regex: /[^1-3]+/g    works fine but it´s not the same for /^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-7][0-9]|180)$/g

Comment: I'm suggesting you wrap `/[^1-3]+/g.test(val)` in parenthesis so that the `!` is applied to the result of the expression.

Comment: @ScottMarcus That doesn't change anything. Member access and function calls have higher precedence than logical not.

Comment: Difference between them is that first expect to string start ^ and end $ but in second case not.

Comment: @Andres Are you sure your second expression is correct? Having the caret `^` inside the brackets `[]` means "don't match what's inside these brackets." Therefore, `[^1-3]` means "don't match 1, 2, or 3", which, when *negated* in your filter callback, means you're only *keeping* 1, 2, or 3.

Comment: Everyone focusing on regex part. Has anyone noticed the `str.split("")` that looks dubious? OP is basically testing the regex against single character.

Comment: @AndresChica Can you tell us what’s the expected behavior and what’s broken with the code? Show us some test case. Currently I don’t understand your intention.

Comment: Also, remove `g` flags, when you use a regex in RegExp#test, the `g` is redundant and sometimes may lead to confusing results.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is a regex that only accepts a range betwen 0 and 180. 
The regex [^1-3] works well, but /^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-7][0-9]|180)$/g doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies on two fronts:

1. Your `var splitStr = str.split("");` line is splitting the string down to individual characters, which means you are never testing '180', but '1', '8', and '0' separately
2. RegEx is a poor tool to validate numerical range

You should *really really really* reconsider using regex for this purpose, and instead should parse the input into a number and test it, unless there's some other reason that you need to do it this way. One reason to parse and test instead is that there may be edge cases that your expression doesn't cover, even though they may be valid.

If, for some reason, you *absolutely must* use regex, you need to test the string(s?) as a whole, rather than char by char, just by using the same `RegExp.prototype.test()` function like you already were:

```js
function regex1(str) {
    return /^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-7][0-9]|180)$/g.test(str);
}

var tests = ['0', '1', '120', '180', '181'];
for (var str of tests)
  console.log(`${str}:`, regex1(str));
```

As an example of an alternate solution:
If you're using HTML `<input>`s for form input, then they already have a mechanism for setting a max (and min) numerical input. Trying to submit with invalid input will prevent form submission:

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" max="180" placeholder="0 - 180">
  <input type="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. There is a reason for use regex instead a function